# Sync source for repository is always skipped despite "checkout: self"

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Our new repo showed 'Skip sync source for repository' even with YAML like below which set steps: -checkout: self

Symptom:
[Skip sync source for repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XewgZ.png)

It's a Java/SCALA repo that needs Maven to work which requires pom.xml files to be synced to the build agent.

So when I update the YAML file, I declared a `checkout: self` option.

YAML file here:
[YAML with checkout: self](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml0vi.png)

But it still showed `Skip sync source for repository`. How can I get sources to be synced to my Azure build agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get sources to be synced to my Azure build agents?

You need to check the setting: **Don't sync sources** in `Yaml -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get Sources.`

[image]

[image]

You can disable the **Don't sync sources** option. Then it will get sources to be synced .

Comment: You save my day! Thank you very much!!